# Worklight [adapter-deployer] SEVERE: Element <port> must be a number

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Currently in the environment being used, the port is not available to be specified all the time.  Within my xml `<connectivity>` settings, the `<port>` will be blank.

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>worklightserver.test.com</domain>
        <port></port>           
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>
```

When calling

```
<adapter-deployer deployable="test.adapter" worklightServerHost="http://192.168.1.9:8080"/>
```

I get the error:

```
[adapter-deployer] SEVERE: Element <port> must be a number.
```

Is this a bug in worklight? I would assume that if a port is not specified, it would use the proper port depending on the protocol specified. With a port specified, it works as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP protocol can work on any port, not necessarily 80. 
Port must be always specified.